# View get packed in ConstraintLayout, Views run out of screen in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I am implementing a signup/login screen like below

[image]

I have tried this using `ConstraintLayout` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_already_member"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_already_member"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Already Member? Sign In"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_agreement"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_agreement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="By continuing you agree to our terms and privacy policy"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Summary of XML:

- Vertical chain is applied on four top most views
- vertical chain style is set to packed
- last text view is constraint to bottom and sides
- margin is set on views to separate items.

Problem is when I run this on my phone, bottom text views get tight packed as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glv7M.png).

Next I tried `LinearLayout` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Button 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_already_member"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Already Member? Sign In"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_agreement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="By continuing you agree to our terms and privacy policy "
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this case bottom text views are not visible as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG5GV.png).

My device resolution is 720 * 1280 pixels.

I suppose the problem is with the hard margins. How could I make the screen look like in the sketch above, regardless of screen height? either using `LinearLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solution to my problem is using `Guideline`s in `ConstraintLayout` with `Guideline`s `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent`attribute and constraining the views to Guidelines.

Since value for `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` is a **percentage** rather than a `dp` value, it works responsively regardless of screen width/height.

example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_already_member"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Already Member? Sign In"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_agreement"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_agreement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="By continuing you agree to our terms and privacy policy "
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".6" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you very much Rehan Sarwar for remembering me about `Guideline`s.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you you use all screen densities rather than one for this you can use the famous library [SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) or follow the guideline provided by [android](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).
Second use Guideline class for Constraintlayout.
Here is the sample code snippet you can also use this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txt_already_member"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_already_member"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Already Member? Sign In"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_agreement"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:text="By continuing you agree to our terms and privacy policy"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@dimen/_16sdp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/_16sdp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_already_member" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of the library, there should be way with constraintlayout or some other layout, since there are apps that I have installed look good on my phone with similar screens.

Comment: I tried your code, there is big gap between bottom two text views

Comment: You can control this by using app:layout_constraintVertical_bias.